# How to get the sObject type from a controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an extension class that I want to share between tasks and events to route the user to the right page.  In my contstructor, I want to determine the sObject type of the controller how do to i do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try:

```
public class myControllerExtension {

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        String type = stdController.getRecord().getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

    }
}
```

You can't get the object type from sObjectType as an string. Try by using  getDescribe().getName();

> Apex provides two data structures for sObject and field describe
>   information:
>
> - Token—a lightweight, serializable reference to an sObject or a field that is validated at compile time.
> - Describe result—an object that contains all the describe properties for the sObject or field. Describe result objects are not
>     serializable, and are validated at runtime.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

Comment: I don't think you need that cast; getRecord() returns an SObject and getSObjectType returns SObjectType.

Comment: Thx for notice that, fixed

Comment: You can also just get it from the Id if the record exists Id.getSObjectType()

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of approaches you can use for this, one is using SObjectType, the other is using the '[instanceof](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_instanceof.htm)' feature in Apex. Using 'instanceof' is more natural from an [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) perspective, and thus Java and C# developers will understand it more than the SObjectType approach. The first depends if you plan to do any Apex Describe type work after, thus the SObjectType is the place to start if so.

```
     SObjectType sObjectType = controller.getRecord().getSObjectType();
     if(sObjectType == Opportunity.sObjectType)
     {
        // This is a Opportunity record
        Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();
     }
     else if(sObjectType == Account.sObjectType)
     {
        // This is a Account record             
        Account acc = (Account) controller.getRecord();
     }


     SObject record = controller.getRecord();
     if(record instanceof Opportunity)
     {
        // This is a Opportunity record
        Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();             
     }
     else if(record instanceof Account)
     {
        // This is a Account record             
        Account acc = (Account) controller.getRecord();             
     }
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Using 'instanceof' is more natural from an OO perspective, and thus Jave and C# developers will understand it more than the SObjectType approach. The first depends if you plan to do any Apex Describe type work after, thus the SObjectType is the place to start if so.

Answer (score 2):

Easy!!

```
public YourExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  String sObjectType = String.valueOf(controller.getRecord().getSObjectType());
}
```

Comment: This will not compile, to make it compile, you need to use the SObjectType variable. SObjectType sObjectType = controller.getRecord().getSObjectType();

Comment: getSObjectType is returning a  Schema.SObjectType not a n String